# Looking for a certain integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering whether an integral exist where the function has no elementary antiderivative, but when integrated over a certain interval, can be integrated by parts infinitely after which the last integral can be shown to vanish if the integration by parts goes on infinitely.

Comment: Integrals do not have antiderivative, but functions...:)

Comment: What's the "last integral" if the integration by parts goes on infinitely?  Perhaps what you mean is a function that can be expanded in an infinite series using integration by parts?

Comment: Well, a function could be turned into a series plus a integral. When we integrate by parts 'infinitely' i mran that we let the amount of times we integrate by parts go to infinity. This should only converge if the integral vanishes as we approach infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what you mean is something like this.  Consider the non-elementary integral
$$ J = \int_0^x \exp(-t^2)\; dt $$
Repeated integration by parts yields
$$ J = x e^{-x^2} + \frac{2}{3} x^3 e^{-x^2} + \frac{2^2}{3 \cdot 5} x^5 e^{-x^2} + \ldots + \frac{2^{n}}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+1)}  x^{2n+1} e^{-x^2} +
\int_0^x \frac{2^{n+1}}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+1)} t^{2n+2} e^{-t^2}\; dt $$
and the sequence of integrals does go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, leaving a convergent series for $J$.